# Allow props.children to be anything when using Typescript with "no-any": true?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to be able to pass anything into my component as `props.children`. My first thought would be to set the type of `props.children` to `any`.

```
interface MyProps {
    children: any;
}
```

But unfortunately we specify `"no-any": true` in out `tsconfig` file.

So the solution that I have found working is:

```
interface TableProps {
    children: JSX.Element[] | JSX.Element | string;
}
```

But this feels very ugly. I dislike having to pass 3 arguments to mimic `any`. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to disallow `any`, you're pretty much going to have to be specific. But that doesn't mean repeating yourself. :-) You can define that union as a type:

```
type ComponentChildren = JSX.Element[] | JSX.Element | string;
```

...then use that type wherever you need to allow all three of those as `children`:

```
interface TableProps {
    children: ComponentChildren;
}
```